# xUnit dotCover msBuild error

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, xunit, dotcover

I am trying to create an MSBuild build to output a dotCover.html report for upload to SonarQube. However - dotCover errors out even though all the Unit Test pass. I don't know where to go from here.

**MsBuild File**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <TestAssemblies Include="**\bin\Release\*.tests.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <dlls>@(TestAssemblies, ' ')</dlls>
  </PropertyGroup>
  //Some other targets
  <Target Name="DotCover">
    <Exec Command='"%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Installations\dotCover04\dotCover.exe" analyse /ReportType=HTML /Output="dotCover.html" /TargetWorkingDir=. /TargetExecutable:"packages\xunit.runner.console.2.1.0\tools\xunit.console.exe" /TargetArguments="$(dlls) -noshadow" /LogFile' />
  </Target>
```

**Error in the dotCover LogFile**

> 15:17:29.682 |I| IteratorsProcessor            | Can't find matching
>   method for iterator class
>   Xunit.Sdk.XunitTestAssemblyRunner+d__14
>   Extracted containing method name: RunTestCollectionsAsync Candidates
>   number: 0 Parent type methods: .ctor; Dispose;
>   GetTestFrameworkDisplayName; GetTestFrameworkEnvironment;
>   SetupSyncContext; Initialize; AfterTestAssemblyStartingAsync;
>   BeforeTestAssemblyFinishedAsync; RunTestCollectionsAsync;
>   RunTestCollectionAsync; SetSynchronizationContext; <>n__0 15:17:29.703
>   |I| IteratorsProcessor            | Can't find matching method for
>   iterator class Xunit.Assert+d__56`1 Extracted containing
>   method name: ThrowsAsync Candidates number: 0 Parent type methods:
>   .ctor; Equals; ReferenceEquals; False; False; False; False; True;
>   True; True; True; All; Collection; Contains; Contains; Contains;
>   DoesNotContain; DoesNotContain; DoesNotContain; Empty; Equal; Equal;
>   NotEmpty; NotEqual; NotEqual; Single; Single; Single; Single;
>   GetComparer; GetEqualityComparer; Equal; Equal; Equal; Equal;
>   StrictEqual; NotEqual; NotEqual; NotEqual; NotEqual; NotStrictEqual;
>   Throws; Throws; Throws; ThrowsAsync; ThrowsAny; ThrowsAny;
>   ThrowsAnyAsync; Throws; Throws; ThrowsAsync; Throws; ThrowsAny;
>   Throws; Throws; Throws; ThrowsAsync; GuardArgumentNotNull;
>   RecordException; RecordException; RecordException;
>   RecordExceptionAsync; NotSame; Same; NotNull; Null; PropertyChanged;
>   InRange; InRange; NotInRange; NotInRange; ProperSubset;
>   ProperSuperset; Subset; Superset; Contains; Contains; DoesNotContain;
>   DoesNotContain; StartsWith; StartsWith; EndsWith; EndsWith; Matches;
>   Matches; DoesNotMatch; DoesNotMatch; Equal; Equal; IsLineEnding;
>   IsWhiteSpace; SkipLineEnding; SkipWhitespace; IsAssignableFrom;
>   IsAssignableFrom; IsNotType; IsNotType; IsType; IsType

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you verify that the pdb's are also being output into your test directory during msbuild?

Comment: @Jonathon Chase Is the test directory the working folder or the location of the .dlls? Either way the answer is probably no because I am using the release build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotCover is unable to process information against the assemblies without having `PDB`s available for use. You can set the `PDB`s to be utilized by either adding `<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>` under the configuration being used for your builds, or adding the `/debug:pdbonly` switch to the compiler line for your project. You can set these through the project's properties on the build panel, through the advanced options section, or by manually editing the csproj. If having the `PDB`s isn't optimal you may be able to set a post condition to run after dotcover to clean them out.

Comment: Thanks for you help. This coupled with the fact I had an old MSTest project also being loaded was why it was not working. Thank you - very much appreciated.